# Phases of Brain Development and Gender Identity

Tags: neuroscience, brain-development, gender

What stages of brain development are represented by sexual differentiation and linked to prenatal development of gender identity?

Comment: Welcome. Is this a homework question? In any case, we like questions to be focused and a great way of doing that is by adding your research efforts so far.